# Library/tool to add user controlled filtering of output to prompt-toolkit based cli

Tags: python

We have a python3 CLI using prompt-toolkit.  We want to give the users of our cli the ability to filter the output of commands to get back the values they want.  ideally this would be done using a | to pass the command output to some sort of filtering.  There has been talk about trying to match jinja look and feel but all we really must have is a clean way to allow users to do filtering.

I'm looking for any library that might plug in nicely with prompt-toolkit to give us out of the box filtering without my having to roll my own logic from scratch.

At minimum we need to filter json for specific fields defined by our users.  Ideally we would like to be able to have the ability to display the results in a table view but I doubt I'm going to find a tool that does that much out of box.